# Array of react elements not rendering in the render()

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I am learning react through creating some sample projects using Meteor. I think I am getting a grasp of it but now I am stuck again.

I am using a twitter API to fetch the most recent 3 tweets from the BOINGBOING twitter page. I can confirm that I have the API working and can console out an array of objects containing `created_at`, `text`, & `value.entities.media[0].media_url` which is basically the image url of a tweet.

What I am trying to achieve is to display the three tweets within a `div` tag containing an `img` & 2 `p` tags.

I am forming the DOM with JSX, pushing the DOM for current tweet into an array and then passing this array to render(). I thinking an array of React elements should render right? So what is my mistake, I am seeing nothing?

```
getTweets: function(){

    Meteor.call('fetchTweets', function(error, result){
        var res = [];

        // cycle through the results and build reat elements
        _.each(result, function(value, key, list){
            var {created_at, text, ...other} = value;

            if (value.entities.media != undefined) {
                // no image
                let node = (
                    <div>
                        <p>{created_at}</p>
                        <p>{text}</p>
                    </div>                        
                    );
                console.log(node);
                res.push(node);

            } else {
                // has image
                let node = (
                    <div>
                        <img src={value.entities.media[0].media_url} alt=""/>
                        <p>{created_at}</p>
                        <p>{text}</p>
                    </div>                        
                );
                res.push(node);

            }
        })
        console.log(res);
        return res;          

    });        
},

render: function() {

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="alltweets">{this.getTweets()}</div>
        </div>          
    );
}
```

When I console out my react elements, this is what I see.
[image]

Comment: what is rendering? also, when rendering an array, the components need to be manually given a `key` propery (which can be set to the index of loop)

Comment: @PhilVarg I will try this

Comment: We really need to see more of this. How are you rendering this to the dom? I don't see anywhere that you're injecting this either by a template helper, or an initializer, or any other way of attaching to the dom. Also, a typical react element begins much differently, I'll post an answer which shows this.

Comment: @thatgibbyguy I am rendering by using `{this.getTweets()}` -> see the console output at the end of the post, I have seen it done this way in another example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know meteor, but it looks like `Meteor.call` is asynchronous, so it can't just return `res`. You'd probably need to call `setState({ someKey: res })` in your asyncCallback , and use that state in your `render()` call.

Comment: true but I am returning `res` within Meteor.call. I tried setting state but this returned strange errors.

Comment: @KevinQi I am using `Meteor.call` with a callback function, I only return `res` within this callback

Comment: @ThaiTran i see `Error: Invariant Violation: Test.getInitialState(): must return an object or null`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're using react correctly in this situation, here's how I'd do it.

```
const TweetList = React.createClass({


    getInitialState() {
        const tweets = Meteor.call('fetchTweets', function(error, result){ 
            return result;
        }
        return { 
            tweets: tweets
        }
    },

    render() {
        const {tweets} = this.state;
        {data.map(this._renderTweets)}
    },

    _renderTweets(tweet, ii) {
        if (!tweet.entities.media) {
            return(
                <div key={ii}>
                    <p>{tweet.created_at}</p>
                    <p>{tweet.text}</p>
                </div> 
            );
        }
        else {
            return(
                <div key={ii}>
                    <img src={tweet.entities.media.media_url} alt=""/>
                    <p>{tweet.created_at}</p>
                    <p>{tweet.text}</p>
                </div> 
            );
        }
    }
});
```

And then you would render that to the DOM.

Comment: Doesnt seem too different from mine. ive not seen `getInitialState` using this way, looks like you are not setting `this.state`, i though `getInitialState` must return an object?  i will give it a go though, thanks

Comment: You're right, `this.data` should be `this.state`. I've edited it.

Comment: Perhaps look at this article that sascha just posted. https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/data-loading-react/

Comment: I got the code to work. The problem was that my contexts were messed up i.e cant `setState` from within a callback function. My solution is still spaghetti code until I find a cool solution to the problem. Thanks for link, here one for you : https://medium.com/meteor-js/how-to-connect-meteor-js-to-an-external-api-93c0d856433b#.qbcc6luo3

Comment: ur solution wont work either, `getInitialState` should an object. Your code returns `null`

Comment: My apologies, it was a late night. I've updated the `getInitialState` to return the proper object. And your link is not about your question. Your question is two parts: part one - how to connect to an external API. You have that solved in your original post. Part two - how to render via react - you did not do that properly. This answer solves part two.

Comment: that wont work either, as the meteor method is async, my solution sets the state from within the callback using a reference to the outer context which look like `self.setState(tweets:tweets)` where `self = this` in root context of `getInitialState`. The outer context sets anyway the state which is eventually overwritten when the Meteor.method callback returns and triggers a re-render